# Reading complex potential into CP2K

Tags: td-dft, cp2k, interatomic-potentials, software-input-file-request, finite-difference-time-domain

Is it possible to read a complex potential into CP2K? I have generated a potential using FDTD at a given frequency, which results in a complex result. The potential is to be read in to a real time propagation method as a static background potential.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting the [manual](https://manual.cp2k.org/trunk/CP2K_INPUT/FORCE_EVAL/DFT/EXTERNAL_POTENTIAL.html#list_FUNCTION) correctly, it is not possible to define a complex external potential in CP2K. It specifies that the `VALUES` keyword to define the corresponding `PARAMETERS` of your potential has to be real. I don't know anything about the internal code of CP2K, so I don't know if this would be a simple modification of the code to accept complex inputs in this function or a more extensive overall of the code to handle complex values throughout.